# WCF Static Variable Getting Reset with Each Call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, static, singleton

I have a WCF service that I am calling from multiple clients. I need to store and manage a value globally. On my service I have the following attributes:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

In my service I have something similar to this:

```
private static int counter;

public void PrintCounter()
{
    counter++;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\outFile.txt", true);
    sw.WriteLine("Counter: " + counter);
    sw.Close();
}
```

With my limited knowledge of WCF, I would presume that I have a Singleton service and the fact that my private variable is static, that all calls to the service would use the same object.

However, when I look at my log output, I see the following:

```
Counter: 1
Counter: 1
```

What I expected to see would be:

```
Counter: 1
Counter: 2
```

Am I missing something to make this work the way I need it to? Do I need to store objects in some sort of cache? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I can post more coded if needed.

Comment: If anyone sees this, the services that required the values for the static variables to remain persistant, we were forced to move them to Net TCP WCF services. We use a RESTful Web Service as a 'router' to call the TCP services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a singleton service, e.g. only one instance will ever exists of it, why don't you make this a regular class member variable??

Since the ConcurrencyMode is set to single, too - you don't even have to worry about concurrent access to the variable.

On the other hand - singleton with ConcurrencyMode=Single is a recipe for a really really slow service which might become a bottleneck quickly - so you might want to program your code in such a way that it would also work under ConcurrencyMode=Multiple with potentially concurrent access to the member variable.

Comment: I removed the [ServiceBehavior] attribute and it does the same thing.

I should note that I am calling my service from 2 different browsers in both cases.

Comment: well, if you don't have a singleton anymore, then each incoming request gets a brand-spanking new instance of the service class, which is disposed after it's done. Nothing "lingers" around in that case for sure.

Comment: My scenario was found while testing session management. When a user logs in, we give them a session GUID that is embedded into an authentication token. The session times out after so many minutes. We were storing it as a static list of GUID's, but with each WCF service session, they get a new session list. I am starting to think it is wiser to push this session information off to some sort of datastore like memcached.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for those like me that are trying to do this, I believe your ServiceBehavior was right.  I think the problem was how you initialized counter which you didn't include in the question.  If you initialize it at declaration, the output is as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only have one server, so this isn't due to load-balancing.

Static data should stick around, unless IIS is recycling the app for some reason?

BTW, you should really use `Interlocked.Increment` for that, but this shouldn't cause the problem you are seeing (unless you are under *massive* load, and you are seeing things like

```
10003120
10003121
10003121
10003121
10003122
```